# HTML list from data stored in Google Spreadsheet for Apps Script website/webapp - Templated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Google Apps Script web app I'm trying to make has a button that the user clicks and adds their name to. I'm trying to have that information save as a list on the website so that if I refresh the page it's still there and if someone else is accessing the website, it will still be there.

This is the add button - https://snag.gy/EOgx5T.jpg
These are example names added from the button- https://snag.gy/8GtX3Y.jpg

I don't want to save it as local storage. Is there a way to save the information to a Google Spreadsheet and use that spreadsheet as a database or something?

index.html

```
<div id="artistTabs">
   <ul id="artistList">
     <li><a onClick="addArtist(); return false;" href="">+</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js.html

```
function addArtist()
{
   console.log("add artist here");
   var artistName = prompt("enter artist whole first name and initial of last name");
    if (artistName === "") //user pressed 'ok' but input field was empty
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (artistName != "" && artistName !== null) //user inputs something and hits 'ok'
    {
         var ul = document.getElementById("artistList");
         var li = document.createElement("li");
         var a = document.createElement("a");
         a.setAttribute("href", "#");
         a.textContent = artistName;
         li.appendChild(a);
         ul.appendChild(li);   
         li.onclick = function()
         {
            test(); return false;
         };
   }
   else //user hits 'cancel' or 'x' 
   {
        return;
   }
}

function test()
{
    console.log("test");
}
```

Do I need to add something to the Google Apps Script 'xxx.gs' or 'xxx.js' file to save the information/access a database/something?

#### Edit

I've updated some of the code. I can write the artist to the spreadsheet and i can get the artist name back from the spreadsheet. I'm still confused on how to display a new item in the list as templated html.

index.html

```
<div id="artistTabs">
    <ul id="artistList">
        <li><a onClick="addArtist(); return false;" href="">+</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js.html

```
function addArtist()
{
  var artistName = prompt("enter artist whole first name and initial of last name");

  if (artistName === "") //user pressed 'ok' but input field was empty
  {
    return;
  }
  else if (artistName != "" && artistName !== null) //user inputs something and hits 'ok'
  {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(writeSuccess(artistName))
      .withFailureHandler(writeFailure)
      .writeArtistName(artistName);
  }
  else //user hits 'cancel' or 'x'
  {
    return;
  }
}

function writeSuccess(artistName)
{
  console.log("write success: " + artistName);
}

function writeFailure()
{
  console.log("write failure - email myself why it failed and the time it failed");
}
```

code.gs

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

function doGet()
{
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function getContent(filename)
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function writeArtistName(artistName)
{
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; //gets next unused row
  var column = 1; //first column
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, column);

  lastCell.setValue(artistName); //sets next blank row as artistName
}

function getArtistName()
{
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //gets last row with content
  var column = 1;

  var lastArtist = sheet.getRange(lastRow, column).getValue(); //gets last row with artistName

  Logger.log(lastArtist);

  var x = '<li><a onClick="test(); return false;" href="#">';
  var y = lastArtist;
  var z = '</a></li>';

  var xyz = x + y + z;

  Logger.log(xyz);
}
```

How do I call the `getArtistName()` function in the code.gs file, set the artist name as a list item in my unordered list, and display it on the website as an html template? i cant call `document.getElementById` in the .gs file because it says `ReferenceError: "document" is not defined`.

i need the list to stay on the website even if i reload the page and it needs to be accessible to anyone from anywhere

Comment: The best option is probably PHP

Comment: @WilliamBrochmann can you elaborate on how i would use php for this?

Comment: You can use something like `cookie`, I refer you to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: @nmnsud it says 'By default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed'. i need the information that the user inputted to be on the website permanently, even after the page is refreshed/closed and opened again.

Comment: So, in that case use **php**, its only choice you can use.

Comment: @nmnsud how would i use php for this? and where do i save the information the user inputted?

Comment: i'm answering below, in that i will give you clear details.

Comment: You can easily save data to a spreadsheet from your Apps Script Web App.  You will need to use the `google.script.run.myServerGS_function()` to interact from the web app to the server code.  I'm assuming that you have a `doGet()` function that is serving the HTML to the browser?  And you have published at least one version?  [Link to Apps Script Documentation - google.script.run client side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: @WilliamBrochmann, there will be a number of ways to solve any question if you throw out enough of the context. As the question was how to achieve something using Google Apps Script, suggesting moving to php is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build HTML on the server.  So change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="artistTabs">
   <ul id="artistList">
      <?!= createTheList(); ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Server Code

```
function createTheList() {
  var artists,howManyRows,howManyColumns,i,L,newList,ss,sh,startingRow,startingColumn,
    thisArtist,templateHTML,thisRow;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('file ID goes here'); //Get spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet tab name');

  startingRow = 2;
  startingColumn = 1;
  howManyRows = sh.getLastRow() - 1;
  howManyColumns = 1;

  artists = sh.getRange(startingRow,startingColumn,howManyRows,howManyColumns)
    .getValues();//Get all artist names
  L = artists.length; //How many artist in the list

  artists = artists.toString().split(",");//Flatten 2D array to 1D

  //template of blank row of HTML with a merge string of "z_z_z_z_z"
  templateHTML = "<li><a onClick="addArtist(); return false;" href="">z_z_z_z_z</a></li>";

  newList = "";//Initialize

  for (i=0;i<L;i+=1) {
    thisRow = "";//reset on every loop
    thisArtist = artists[i];

    thisRow = templateHTML.replace("z_z_z_z_z",thisArtist);//Inject artist name
    newList = newList + thisRow;//Keep adding to the list
  };

  return newList;
};
```

You can send the data to a Google Spreadsheet.  In your case, the value collected has a variable name of `artistName`.  So you can call an Apps Script function in a `.gs` file like this:

### GS File:

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(data) {
  var ss, sh;

  //Save data to a spreadsheet
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('file ID goes here'); //Get spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet tab name');
  sh.appendRow([data]);//Append data to end of sheet tab data
};
```

### Client Side Code:

```
<script>
  function someFunctionName(artistName) {//Either pass data to function
    //Or get the data
    var artistName = code to get the value;

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(serverCodeCompleted)
     .writeToSpreadsheet(artistName);
  };

  function serverCodeCompleted() {
    //Show message to the user
    some code here
  };
</script>
```

To get the data to display in your page, you should use templated HTML.

[Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: i understand the writing the information to the spreadsheet part. i dont get how i would have that information become permanent on the website until i want it gone. the templated html is very confusing...do i do js functions in the html file with the '<?= ?>' tag around it? if so, do i just take my whole addArtist function and put it in there?

Comment: See updated answer.  You must also change your `doGet()` function to add:  `createTemplateFromFile('HTML file name').evaluate()`

Comment: its giving me 'ReferenceError: "createTheList" is not defined. '. also the server code is for the '.js' file? and i dont need the gs file and client side code for the html and server code right?

Comment: Sandy, as a suggestion, OP has not done any research or tried to save data to a sheet. Its best to let the user research and try first, there are plenty or resources including duplicate questions to this one in SO that explain the task.giving the answer without effort creates more issues as the op usually isnt ready for the answer.